# Polygon Construction for Specified Number of Interior and Boundary Lattice Points

Tags: geometry, construction

> **Construct a simple polygon on a grid of equal-distanced points such that:**
>
> 1. all the polygon's vertices are grid points,
> 2. there are exactly $i~(\geq 0)$ lattice points in the interior, and
> 3. there are exactly $b~(\geq 3)$ lattice points on the boundary.

**As a practice, construct it for:**

- $i = 5$ and $b = 12$
- $i = 0$ and $b = 10$
- $i = 9$ and $b = 3$

**As for examples:**

[image: examples]

- On the left side, it's a polygon with $5$ interior points and $16$ boundary points.
- On the right side, it's a polygon with $9$ interior points and $10$ boundary points.

---

<sub><sup>This puzzle was submitted (but not accepted) for [The 31st International Olympiad in Informatics (IOI 2019)](https://ioi2019.az/).</sup></sub>

Comment: What do you want us to answer, exactly?

Comment: How to construct such polygon, for all $i$ and $b$.

Comment: Isn't this more math than informatics?  I thought IOI was a computing olympiad.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 sometimes it has ad-hoc and constructive problems where logic and creativity are needed. It may also cover numerous math problems like game theory. IMHO the difference with math olympiad is algorithm/construction vs rigorous (mathematical) proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the answer for practice ones:

1:

> [image]

2:

> [image]

3:

To construct b=3;

> You just need to make a bigger triangle for all i's.

As show below for i=9.

> [image]

The general idea is actually the same as above, if you want to increase b

> you just need to visit extra points for the triangle while controlling your i value.

for example, if you want b=5 and i=9;

> [image]

or for example, if you want b=20 and i=9;

> [image]

So you should

> decide your $i$ first as a triangle b=3, then increase b as much as you want on the grid to control the value of b.

so you can create polygons with every $i\geq0$ and $b\geq3$ values with the method above.

Comment: Yep, this will work! Of course there are a lot of other ways (which may be easier -- or harder -- than your construction). Anyway, congrats!